# Removing non-alphanumeric characters from string in XSL

Tags: xslt

How do I remove non-alphanumeric characters from a string in XSL?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you define non-alphanumeric as `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="
  translate(
    string,
    translate(
      string, 
      'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',
      ''
    ),
    ''
  )
" />
```

Note that this is for XSLT 1.0. In XSLT 2.0 you can work with regexes directly, using [`replace()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is right: [the XSLT translate function](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_translate.html) takes three strings. All of the content of the _second_ string will be replaced by those in the _third_ string. This means the above code will remove all alpha-numeric characters.

Comment: @RossAngus It removes the alphanumeric characters from the string to get a list of non-alphanumeric characters. It then takes *that* list to remove them from the input.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.

Answer (score 9):

For XSLT 2.0 you can use `replace()` as follows:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(<string>, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '')" />
```