# Replace some characters explicitly given in XSLT

Tags: xslt, replace, special-characters

I saw many answers to this question (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666103/how-to-replace-all-special-characters-in-a-string-with-spaces) one) who match a (little) pool of alloweded characters with `translate(input, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '')` instead of matching directly unhallowed characters.

I need to proceed by the reverse way because the characters I want to remain are, basically wool Unicode, when the ones I want to replace with dash are just : `!$&'*+,-./:;=?@_~`.

So, how to match the characters bellow and only these ones, to replace them by dash?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What you mean is that if you have a string like "abc!def$gh", you would want it to become "abc-def-gh"?

Comment: Does this answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1267981/3710053

Comment: What exactly is "dash"? Your list of characters to replace includes `-` (HYPHEN-MINUS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to do:

```
<xsl:value-of select='translate(input, "!$&amp;&apos;*+,-./:;=?@_~", "-----------------")'/>
```